# Render form in cycle

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tapestry

This question is about **Tapestry 4** (not Tapestry 5). 
If I try to render form component in the cycle, and submit one form, validation displays errors in both of them because tapestry creates only one form instance and reuse it. Seems that I need to provide unique id for each of the forms, but I don't know how.
Here is the code to reproduce the issue:

```
    <block jwcid="formBlock@Block">
        <form jwcid="@Form">
            <input jwcid="@TextField" value="literal:" validators="validators:required" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </block>
    <for jwcid="@Foreach" source="ognl:new int[]{1,2}">
        <span jwcid="@RenderBlock" block="component:formBlock" />
    </for>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the validation errors display twice in the browser is because in reality you only have one form; you're just rendering it twice. If you want each form to have separate validation handling, then you must create two separate @Form components.